# Plane geometry question

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle.

$D$ is on $BC$ and $\angle BAD = 20^\circ$.

Also let $I_1$, $I_2$ be the inner centers of triangles $ABD$, $ACD$ respectively.

$E$ is a point making the triangle $I_1I_2E$ be equilateral ($D$ and $E$ are on the opposite side of the line $I_1I_2$.

Then what is the $\angle ADE$?

This is my question and I tried to find $4$ cyclic points or something like that, but I have no idea.

Please help me.

Comment: You should add a diagram of this: what has the point $\;E\;$ to do with triangle $\;I_1I_2B\;$ ?? Also, from what I could gather, this triangle $\;I_1I_2B\;$ is going to have a non-acute angle *always* ....Very unclear.

Comment: Sorry i edited..